# How to Add a Fixed Value to a Select List?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select Column1 From Table1;
```

Output :

```
x1
x2
x3
x4
```

the output will BE in Column1.

I want THE results to be :

```
OTHERS 
x1 
x2 
x3 
x4
```

I want to add the "OTHERS" value to Column1.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest wway of doing this:

```
select column1 from table1
union all
select 'OTHERS' from dual
```

Hmmm, probably second easiest way, because the easiest way of doing it would be:

```
insert into table1 (column1) values 'OTHERS';
```

Although no doubt you have some cast-iron business rule why you don't want to do this.

To get your desired ordering:

```
select * from (
    select column1 from table1
    union all
    select 'OTHERS' from dual
)
order by decode(column1, 'OTHERS', 1, 2), column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION:

```
Select 'OTHERS' AS Column1 From DUAL
UNION
Select Column1 From Table1
```